# Remove extra whitespace from output CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to render a dynamically created xml data. Everything is working fine EXCEPT for some reason CodeIgniter adds unnecessary extra whitespace at the beginning of the document.
[image]

Here's what I have tried so far but with no luck:

1. just simply loading the view
2. used simpleXmlElement to render the xml directly inside the controller
3. just left the controller method empty.

   `public function whateverControllerMethod(){ // empty with no code }`

Comment: Make sure you don't have any space before the opening `<?php`-tag in _any_ of the files loaded (used) in the request. Also, make sure that you _don't_ close the PHP-blocks `?>` in the end of the files (since a space after it also would cause this issue). Also make sure that you don't save your files encoded as "utf8 with BOM".

Comment: Codeigniter does nothing its you who prints the empty space out ... you just have to find that whitespace.

Comment: You can use the function [headers_sent()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php) for this. Just run that function (with the `$filename` and `$line` arguments) right before you output your xml to find where the space was outputted. Then, if that function returns true, you can check those variables to find what file and line the output comes from.

Answer (score 1):

Check if in the top of models or controllers there is whitespace or lines before of tag php, because sometimes if used the file autoload.php that is in the path application/config and load all models and if there is whitespace or lines before of tag php in the models then the output from the function of controller will be with extra whitespace.

In my case, this was my problem:

[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eN6lk.png)